# Can a lambda function return a pointer type?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I am thinking of something like this:

```
auto c = []() -> (int*) {int * b; b = new int(); b[0]=2; return b;};
```

Sorry if the cuestion is quite stupid but I am not sure why this produces a compile error:

> ```
> main.cpp:3:18: error: expected type-specifier before '(' token
>  auto c = []() -> (int*) {int * b; b = new int(); b[0]=2; return b;};
> ```

Comment: Consider reading the error message.

Comment: Also, `b[0]=2`, when you have `new int()` isn't undefined, but is close to being so (ie, `b[1]=2` would be undefined).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works perfectly (without `()` around the return type):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto c = []() -> int* { int *b = new int(); b[0] = 2; return b; };
    std::cout << *c() << std::endl;
}
```

(Didn't bother to `delete`)

[**Live on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9dd2e47ecdf2f2c)

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

Remove the parenthesis around `int*`. You don't declare variables like `(int*) p`, so why parenthesis in return type?

This compiles correctly:

```
auto c = []()->int* {int * b; b = new int(); b[0]=2; return b;};
```